# How to control keys to show in Json Object

Tags: json, node.js, couchbase

I am using following NodeJs code to get the JsonObject:

```
cdb.getMulti(['emp1','emp2'],null, function(err, rows) {
    var resp = {};
    for(index in rows){ 
        resp[index] = rows[index];
    }
    res.send(resp);
});
```

Getting output :

```
{
"emp1": {
"cas": {
"0": 637861888,
"1": 967242753
},
"flags": 0,
"value": {
"eid": "10",
"ename": "ameen",
"gender": "male",
"designation": "manager",
"country": "Singapur",
"reportee": "Suresh",
"salary": 50000,
"picture": "ameen.jpg"
}
},
"emp2": {
"cas": {
"0": 721747968,
"1": 430939000
},
"flags": 0,
"value": {
"eid": "2",
"ename": "shanmugapriya",
"gender": "female",
"designation": "programmer",
"country": "England",
"reportee": "shruti",
"salary": 14250,
"picture": "priya.jpg"
}
}
}
```

What I want to do is, I want to display only value key. Can anybody help me how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please send your client side code

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to display only value and key? If so the code below will put only value into the result

```
cdb.getMulti(['emp1','emp2'],null, function(err, rows) {
    var resp = {};
    for(index in rows){ 
        resp[index] = rows[index].value;
    }
    res.send(resp);
});
```

The result response will be

```
{
  "emp1":{
    "eid":"10",
    "ename":"ameen",
    "gender":"male",
    "designation":"manager",
    "country":"Singapur",
    "reportee":"Suresh",
    "salary":50000,
    "picture":"ameen.jpg"
  },
  "emp2":{
    "eid":"2",
    "ename":"shanmugapriya",
    "gender":"female",
    "designation":"programmer",
    "country":"England",
    "reportee":"shruti",
    "salary":14250,
    "picture":"priya.jpg"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Your question was really ambiguous. I think you would need to use Couchbase Views here. Docs http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-node-1.2/#querying-a-view. Assuming that you will build the view `_design/employees/_view/all` with the following `map` function:

```
function(doc, meta) {
   emit(meta.id, doc);
}
```

Your node.js code will look like this

```
var view = bucket.view('employees', 'all');
view.query(function(err, results) {
  res.send(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. 

    I have another doubt. In my code I am passing employees ID manually like :
   " cdb.getMulti(['emp1','emp2'],null, function(err, rows) { "

But I want to fetch all employees. How to do that???

Comment: I have created a view in couchbase named as "employees" and ddoc as "_design/dev_all" with map function :

    function(doc, meta) {
      if(doc.eid)
       emit(meta.eid, doc);
    }

now in node.js I am executing code:
    
    var view = db.view('employees', 'all');
        view.query(function(err, results) {
            res.send(results);
 });
But it is not fetching any data. What can be the wrong?

Comment: db.view('dev_all', 'employees')